# How to pre-render a modal in Expo Router

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo-router

I am using Expo Router v3 and have a modal that takes a noticeable amount of time to render whenever the modal is navigated to.  Assuming I can't optimize the modal rendering, is there any way to pre-render the modal so it has already done its first render offscreen before the modal is navigated to and brought into view?